# html 5 slider onchange event

Tags: html, slider, dom-events, onchange

I am trying to programatically create HTML 5 slider

```
var inputElem = document.createElement("input");
inputElem.id = "opacity_" + layer.name;
inputElem.name = "opacity_" + layer.name;
inputElem.type = "range";
inputElem.min = "0";
inputElem.max = "100"; //debugger;
inputElem.value = "100";
inputElem.step= "1";
inputElem.style.zIndex = "10000";
var fnChange = function () {alert(layer.name) ; };
inputElem.onchange = fnChange;
```

However I **can't set the onchange event**, it stays null, and when viewed in the browser there is **no onchange** as in

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100">
```

I am using Google Chrome 10.0.648.134

What have I done wrong?

Comment: This is a non-issue, somehow the onchange event is set correctly even though it is not displayed when the element is inspected in Google Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: Use the onmouseup event instead. See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165579/onchange-event-for-html5-range

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no native onchange event, but jquery provides one: [onChange event for HTML5 range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165579/onchange-event-for-html5-range)