# Instant event on HTML5 range input

Tags: javascript, html, range

This is a partly reference to this: [onChange event for HTML5 range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165579/onchange-event-for-html5-range)

But what I need is exactly the opposite thing. While the user still moves the tip of the slider, an event should be fired on each value change. For example if I want to use a slider for 3d css rotation or a color picker or something like this. Since this "bug" seems to be corrected in the browsers meanwhile, it would be interesting to know if it is possible to change the event firing "mode" back to how it was initially implemented.

I tested this with a small hack by reading the value in the *onmousemove* event. Is this the correct way (and only one?) or is there a clean solution to do this?

Please no jQuery.

Comment: oninput is what you want, which works for mouse, KB, and AT

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I knew about the onchange event. It works in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari but not in IE (not even in version 11) which is why I asked. It just confuses me that IE 11 doesn't support it if the event is defined as standard.