# Meteor `change` value appears when mouse released, not as input slider is dragged?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I just ported a rough prototype from pure Javascript to Meteor.

In pure Javascript I was using the following code to update certain elements as they're dragged with values from various sliders (`input type="range"`):

```
myElement.addEventListener("input", function() {
  update stuff here…
```

and the values updated as I dragged the slider.

In Meteor, I'm using the code below to trigger the update function for all the sliders:

```
'change input[type=range]': function(event) {
  update stuff here…
```

But the values only appear when I release the mouse button. What is the best/simplest/minimal alternative to Meteor's `change` that will show the values *as the sliders are dragged*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use Meteor's `onRendered` function with your template for the slider and use your original JS.

So something like this

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.TEMPLATENAMEHERE.onRendered(function(){ 
      myElement.addEventListener("input", function() {
      update stuff here…
    });
 })    
}
```

Here is a relevant link:

[onChange event for HTML5 range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165579/onchange-event-for-html5-range)

Alternatively you could just use the **mouseup** event rather than the change event

Comment: Agreed, although `.onRendered` fails, adding my event listener in `.rendered` works to update the DOM with the slider values *as they're changed*: `Template.TEMPLATE_NAME.rendered = function() { …eventListener stuff…` - it's just that I'd hoped Meteor would handle this. BTW mouseUp would cause the same issue - no update until mouseUp.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jQuery slider, you should use the `slide` option when you call `.slider()`.  Meteor has no way of doing this natively.

Comment: Thanks, although I'm not using JQuery slider, just (for now) adding my working native js to the Meteor app, with the trigger as Meteor's `'change input[type=range]'` which only updates the DOM on mouseup after the slider s released, rather than using a native js `addEventListener` which allows me to update the DOM *as the slider is dragged*.