# What is the DOM event when slider button stops moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to make an ajax request whenever the slider button changes from moving to stopping, what is the event for that called?

Temporarily, I am using `oninput` event that calls `clipLimitChange(value)` to `console.log(value)`. I am looking for another event that will call `clipLimitChange()` only when the slider stops sliding, not while it is sliding.

Slider HTML code:

```
<input type="range" id="clipLimit" style="display: none;" value="2.0" min="0.1" max="5.0" step="0.1" oninput="clipLimitChange(value)">
```

The function should be called whenever user changes the slider and dropped it. Not while user is sliding it.

[image]

Comment: Could you post what JavaScript you have so far?

Comment: the javascript I have is only for clipLimitChange(value) which prints out the value. However, I do not want to use onchange() event because it calls clipLimitchange while sliding.

Comment: try on focusout or on blur

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onChange event for HTML5 range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165579/onchange-event-for-html5-range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onchange event will be triggered once the range stops moving.

```
<input type="range" id="clipLimit" style="display: none;" value="2.0" min="0.1" max="5.0" step="0.1" onchange="clipLimitChange(value)">
```

Comment: clipLimitChange is printing the value - I slide the slider and it prints the value while I was moving as well, so onchange() calls the function while the slider is moving, which is what I don't want. I want it to be called only when the moving stops.

Comment: The code supplied here (using `onchange`, not `oninput`, and removing the `style="display:none"`) works on Chrome 53.0.2785.143 m (64-bit) and Firefox 49.0.1 on Windows 8.1. It does not log the value until the user stops moving the button and releases the mouse button. I should say it works once I removed the `style="display: none;"` from the HTML...

Comment: Note that I did find the incorrect behavior in IE11. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5165579

Comment: Apologies for my misunderstanding - onchange() solves the problem. Thank you smooch for your help! Again, sorry for my misunderstanding.